# hasAndBelongsToMany in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I need help for the simple relationchip in cakephp 2.x, I believe this right however not working:

**Customer.php (Model)**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Note' => array(
        'className' => 'Note',
        'joinTable' => 'customers_notes',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'note_id',
        'unique' =>false,
        'dependent'=>true,
    )
);
```

**Note.php (Model)**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Customer' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'joinTable' => 'customers_notes',
        'foreignKey' => 'note_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'unique' =>false,
        'dependent'=>true
    )
);
```

**CustumersController.php (Controller I make the find)**

```
public function admin_notes($id=null){
    $this->layout="Adm.admin";

    $all = $this->Customer->Note->find('all', array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'conditions' => array(
            "CustomersNote.customer_id" => $id
        ),
        'order'=>'CustomersNote.id DESC'
    ));
    $this->set('notes', $all);
}
```

**The error**

```
SQL Query: SELECT `Note`.`id`, `Note`.`titulo`, `Note`.`conteudo`, `Note`.`created`, `Note`.`modified`, `Note`.`user_id` FROM `crm_prado`.`notes` AS `Note` WHERE `CustomersNote`.`customer_id` = '1' LIMIT 10
```

Thanks!

Comment: try :- `$all = $this->Customer->Note->find('all', array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'conditions' => array(
            "Note.customer_id" => $id
        ),
        'order'=>'Note.id DESC'
    ));
    $this->set('notes', $all);
}
`

Comment: Hi, @A-2-A 

``Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Note.customer_id' in 'where clause'``


``SQL Query: SELECT `Note`.`id`, `Note`.`titulo`, `Note`.`conteudo`, `Note`.`customer_id234234`, `Note`.`created`, `Note`.`modified`, `Note`.`user_id` FROM `crm_prado`.`notes` AS `Note` WHERE `Note`.`customer_id` = '1' LIMIT 10``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soluction is really simple.

**In find uses**

```
$all = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
        'recursive'=>2,
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Customer.id'=>$id
        )
 ));
```

**Works!**, but now the recursive mode don't work...